# iText 7 get height of the table before adding to the document

Tags: c#, itext7

I want to get height of the table before adding it to the document. Get the height of the table and check whether the table height is enough for the remaining spaces in the page. If the remaining spaces is enough, add the table otherwise put the table in new page. Please help me to get height of the table and get the current position of the document. 
Thanks

Comment: The answer of the duplicate question has one special part that needs explaining: you can't calculate the height of a table if you don't know the width. That's why a rectangle is defined: `New Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 10000.0F)`. In this case, the rectangle has a width of 400 (the actual width for that user) and a height of 10,000 (much higher than expected). The table will be *"virtually rendered"* inside that rectangle, after which you'll know the actual height.

Comment: I tried to get table height like this. "  LayoutResult = table.CreateRendererSubTree().SetParent(doc.GetRenderer()).Layout(New LayoutContext(New LayoutArea(1, New Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 10000.0F))))
tableHeight = result.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetHeight() "   But it gives higher table hight than the actual table height. How to get actual table height?

Comment: As I explained in the comment: the `400` was the value needed by the other user. Only you know what value you need. We can't guess the width you want to give your table, can we?

Comment: Thanks.. I could resolve it by using extact width of the document.